# Call a "static" method belonging to a generic type in scala

Tags: scala

Is there a way in scala to call a method belonging to a type? For example, suppose I have a trait called `Constructable` that describes types than can construct a default instance of themselves. Then, I can write the following code:

```
  trait Constructable[A] {
    def construct: A
  }

  class Foo(x: Int) extends Constructable[Foo] {
    def construct = new Foo(0)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val f = new Foo(4)
    println(f.construct)
  }
```

This is ok, but what I really want is to be able to construct a default object given only the type of object. For example, suppose I want to accept a list of constructables and prepend a default object at the beginning of the list:

```
  def prependDefault1[A <: Constructable[A]](c: List[A]): List[A] = {
    val h = c.head
    h.construct :: c
  }
```

The above code works, but only if c is not empty. What I'd really like is to write something like the following:

```
  def prependDefault2[A <: Constructable[A]](c: List[A]): List[A] = {
    A.construct :: c
  }
```

Is there any way to achieve this, possibly by changing the definition of a `Constructable` so that the `construct` method belongs to the "class" rather than the "instance" (to use Java terminology)?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is one candidate use of implicit parameters (so a factory object can be passed, without stating it explicitly). Is this reasonable, or totally wrong?

Comment: Scala has static methods, though, just like in java, they do not participate in inheritance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this way, but you can do this using typeclasses:

```
trait Constructable[A] {
  def construct: A
}

// 'case' just so it's printed nicely
case class Foo(x: Int)

// implicit vals have to be inside some object; omitting it here for clarity
implicit val fooConstructable = new Constructable[Foo] {
  def construct = new Foo (0)
}

def prependDefault2[A : Constructable](c: List[A]): List[A] = {
  implicitly[Constructable[A]].construct :: c
}
```

And then:

```
scala> prependDefault2(Nil: List[Foo])
res7: List[Foo] = List(Foo(0))
```

Some final remarks:

Implicits have to live inside an object. There are three places it can be located:

- `object Constructable { implicit val fooConstructable = ...` (companion object of the typeclass trait)
- `object Foo { implicit val fooConstructable = ...` (companion object of the class we implement typeclass for)
- `object SomethingElse { implicit val fooConstructable = ...` (some random unrelated object)

Only in the last case you need to use `import SomethingElse._` in order to be able to use the implicit.

Comment: Great! What is the difference between this approach and using an implicit parameter (i.e., defining `def prependDefault1[A](c: List[A])(implicit f: Contructable[A])...`?

Comment: The only difference is syntax; it's treated by the compiler as the exactly same thing. Pick whichever one you prefer.